# Can I change an item in a style in Xamarin.Android at runtime?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have been hunting around here for a while and have found some answers but none are particularly clear nor do any work for what I need.

I have in styles.xml

```
<resources>
   <declare-styleable name="Sensor">
      <attr name="path12" format="color" />
      <attr name="path24" format="color" />
      <attr name="path36" format="color" />
      <attr name="path48" format="color" />
      <attr name="path60" format="color" />
   </declare-styleable>
   <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
      <item name="path12">@color/plus15</item>
      <item name="path24">@color/plus7</item>
      <item name="path36">@color/nodata</item>
      <item name="path48">@color/nodata</item>
      <item name="path60">@color/nodata</item> 
   </style>
</resources>
```

and in colors.xml:

```
<resources>
    <color name="plus15">#0066ff</color>
    <color name="plus7">#0cb458</color>
    <color name="minus7">#4afe33</color>
    <color name="minus15">#ffff23</color>
    <color name="below15">#ff0c0c</color>
    <color name="nodata">#ffff</color>
</resources>
```

All I want to do is at runtime based on some condition, change the color assigned to path36 (or path24 or whatever) from nodata to minus15

```
<item name="path36">@color/nodata</item>
```

would become

```
<item name="path36">@color/minus15</item>
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Changing the title as this is not Xamarin.Forms but Xamarin.Android (native)

Comment: Seems to be a stumper to more than just me

Comment: In general, if we want to change to different color, we can refer to different color item instead of trying to change the value of a color item.

Comment: Ok, how do you do that?

Comment: To be clear, how would you do that at runtime?